# Regular expression for finding malformed quoted strings

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to build an regular expression for sub string which have a starting quote but didn't have ending quote. Below is an sample string

```
"The fish was 2 long. I said: Give me that fish!.
The fish was 2" long. I said: Give me that fish!.
"The fish was 2 long. I said: Give me that fish!."
The fish "was 2 long". I said: "Give me that fish!.
```

So the valid output for the expression would be

```
String 1 - The fish was 2 long. I said: Give me that fish!
String 2 -  long. I said: Give me that fish!.
String 3 - No output
String 4 - Give me that fish!.
```

Any thoughts how I can build the regular expression.

Comment: A regex is the wrong tool here. E.g. simply counting and outputing after the the last " if there is an odd number of " is much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing all with regex can be done.. will take some more time to perfect the solution. But using some strings function will make it bit easy for you.

Hope this helps!!

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"regexp"
"strings"
)

func main() {
str := `
    "The fish was 2 long. I said: Give me that fish!.
The fish was 2" long. I said: Give me that fish!.
"The fish was 2 long. I said: Give me that fish!."
""sdfsdf
`
splitStr := strings.Split(str, "\n")
re := regexp.MustCompile(`"{1}[A-Za-z0-9 .:!]+"{0}[A-Za-z0-9 .:!]+$`)
for _,v := range splitStr {
    if len(strings.Trim(v, " ")) >= 0{
    // some extra check
    if strings.Count(v, "\"") % 2 == 1 {
        fmt.Println( re.FindString(v))
    }

    } 
}
```

}

Code sample available here: https://play.golang.org/p/LYte6FRocv3